# Create php webserver without command line access?

Tags: php, node.js, ssh, webserver

Im trying to host a website (or figure out how in the world to do such a thing) and I know node.js so If I could get access to the command line on the server I use I could start a node server and do all the work for the website (am I correct on this?)

The problem is I can't figure out how to get ssh access through my host's server (2freewebhost.com - can't figure out ssh remotely... And another host 000webhost.com - though this doesn't offer ssh)

But they offer php

Im not fluent in php (yet).

Does anyone know how to start a php webserver or something to help me use php to start a node server?

Or to even just use php to be my first initial page load and I can to over completely with client side JavaScript from there

Thanks for any advice and/or help

Comment: I've found that calling 1-800-YOUR-WEB-HOST and telling them to go visit [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38331953/2191572) usually resolves the issue.

Comment: Most traditional LAMP-style shared hosts like that do not offer node.js. You would need to use a VPS or a PaaS like Heroku to legitimately use node.js.

Answer (score 0):

So after two stack overflow questions getting absolutely trashed on down votes I figured it out.

You can view my crappy looking startup website at

www.yourcreations.tk

It was 100% free for me to get this working. $0 for hosting, $0 for the domain name. ^_^ I am so happy right about how everything turned out on my journey.

For anyone else who wants to do what I did Ill give you some insight:

https://aws.amazon.com

THE FIRST 12 MONTHS ARE NO CHARGE, after that there will be a charge. Their services are fine for what I need them for. I think its worth paying after the 12 months though, because it was so easy.

By the way, my original question was start a node web server without command line access (pretty much)

Amazon uses elastic beanstalk to restart the web server if it goes down. Its really amazing honestly.

They are using express.js for the server side in node (yay node!). I wish to one day update it to nginx but that is above my head for the moment.

Basically all you do is create yourself (on your local development box) a Webserver and be able to access the site on your localhost.
  I.e. http://localhost.com
From there your project directory should look something like

masterDirectoryName/
  javascriptSourceFilesDirectory/
  cssSourceFilesDirectory/
  anythingElseFilesDirectory/

Your directory order doesn't matter a bit as long as your localhost is up and running (although you'll want to develop standards for this later)

The point is - DO NOT just `zip` up the 'masterDirectoryName' directory/folder.

`zip` up strictly the files that are INSIDE the masterDirectoryName

So in my example zip up:

javascriptSourceFilesDirectory
  cssSourceFilesDirectory
  anythingElseFilesDirectory

Then in your amazon web service site they have very very simple tutorials on how to upload AND deploy those files. It was so easy once I found them its ridiculous.

I think its elastic beanstalks help though. Not for sure, I didn't have to learn anything crazyy to make it work.